# Markers in the Google Map are not responding to any click actions

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, google-maps-markers

I have been working on an application, which uses the Google Maps and Firebase Firestore database to showcase a static list of locations stored in the Firestore database. I want the markers in the pre defined locations to be clickable and on clicking should display a dialog box projecting a few extra data.

I have written the code referring a few online resources, but it doesn't seem to work. Kindly help as I am new to android development.

Below are the files which shows my code. Please help.

MapsActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.example.opshiva.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1;
    private ActivityMapsBinding binding;
    FirebaseFirestore firestoreDB;

    Location currentLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        //instance of Firestore Database
        firestoreDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        getLastLocation();

    }
    private void getLastLocation() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if(location != null){
                    currentLocation = location;

                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        addMarkersfromFirestore();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {

        Log.d("MarkerClick", "Marker clicked: " + marker.getTitle());
        String markerID = marker.getId();
        fetchDataFromFirestore(markerID);
        return true;
    }


    private void addMarkersfromFirestore() {

        firestoreDB.collection("MEDICAL")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                        for(DocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots ){
                            double latitude = document.getDouble("LATITUDE");
                            double longitude = document.getDouble("LONGITUDE");
                            LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            String title = document.getString("NAME");
                            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(location)
                                    .title(title));
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location,10f));
                            Log.d("MarkerDetails", "Title: " + marker.getTitle() +
                                    ", Position: " + marker.getPosition());
                        }

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Exception Occurred in markers", "" + e.getMessage());

                    }
                });

    }
    private void fetchDataFromFirestore(String markerID) {
        
        firestoreDB.collection("MEDICAL")
                .document(markerID)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        
                        if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                            showDataDialog(documentSnapshot);
                        }
                        
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Exception Occurred in reading data", "" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
        
    }

    private void showDataDialog(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

        String oneField = documentSnapshot.getString("NAME");
        String twoField = documentSnapshot.getString("Phone");
        String threeField = documentSnapshot.getString("LATITUDE");
        String fourField = documentSnapshot.getString("LONGITUDE");

        MarkerDetailsDialogFragment dialogFragment = MarkerDetailsDialogFragment.newInstance(oneField,twoField,threeField,fourField);
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"MarkerDetailsDialog");




    }
    
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION){
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
                getLastLocation();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

MarkerDetailsDialogFragment.java

```
public class MarkerDetailsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_NAME = "NAME";
    private static final String ARG_Phone = "Phone";
    private static final String ARG_LATITUDE = "LATITUDE";
    private static final String ARG_LONGITUDE = "LONGITUDE";

    public static MarkerDetailsDialogFragment newInstance(String name, String phone, String latitude, String longitude){

        MarkerDetailsDialogFragment fragment = new MarkerDetailsDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_NAME,name);
        args.putString(ARG_Phone,phone);
        args.putString(ARG_LATITUDE,latitude);
        args.putString(ARG_LONGITUDE,longitude);

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.window_box, null);

        TextView oneTV = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_1);
        TextView twoTV = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_2);
        TextView threeTv =view.findViewById(R.id.textView_3);
        TextView fourTV = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_4);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if(args != null){
            oneTV.setText(args.getString(ARG_NAME));
            twoTV.setText(args.getString(ARG_Phone));
            threeTv.setText(args.getString(ARG_LATITUDE));
            fourTV.setText(args.getString(ARG_LONGITUDE));
        }
        builder.setView(view);


        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

[image: My Firestore Database image]

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors? Besides that, if you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-display-locations-from-firestore-on-google-maps-using-jetpack-compose-9490c92c34da) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreGoogleMapsJetpackCompose).

Comment: @AlexMamo, thank you for your response. the markers on the map does not open up any dialog box, when being clicked. The code as such shows no errors and even the logcat looks clean. Also I have already gone through the attached resource, but didn't get much help.

Comment: Is your `onMarkerClick` method even triggered?

Comment: Yes. It is. But I have worked out a solution, seems like the document ID that was being passed to the fetchDataFromMethod(); was wrong. Thanks @AlexMamo for your help.